# Alternative to 51degrees.mobi?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mobile, 51degrees

Since the mobile detection solution for ASP.NET 51degrees.mobi became commercial (the lite version isn't really useful anymore), I'm looking for an alternative solution.
Are there any other OpenSource or free projects, that enhance the detection of mobile devices with ASP.NET?

Comment: I'm from the 51Degrees.mobi project. We've adopted a "Freemium" model where the source code, and one data set is free and licenced under MPL. The premium option is charged for and includes a greater range of properties. To help us better understand your needs could you let us know which properties you'd like to see in the Lite version of 51Degrees.mobi? Thanks, James

Comment: I only need a solution to detect, if the current device is a phone, a tablet, or desktop. I need no routing and additional parameters like JS or ScreenSize are nice but not essential.

Comment: I too am interested in an answer. WURFL and 51 degrees are clearly targeted at free or big corporate developers only leaving small commercial shops completely out in the cold.

Perhaps we don't need that kind of data after all, perhaps we just need to know some basics that can be covered by media queries?

Comment: This is worth a read: http://www.scientiamobile.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=62

Answer (score -3, accepted):

WURFL should handle your needs: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Looks like a nice idea: Using the old version of 51degrees and only updating the WURLF.xml file ...

Comment: Wurfl is now licensed as well unless you're non profit or are content with only ever using the July 2011 version of the data.  (how can an entity get away with licensing data that people freely contributed from all over?)

Comment: This is a disturbing trend. Crowd-sourced work that is gathered up, packaged and re-licensed, effectively cutting out the contributors. I didn't contribute to the Wurfl project but I'd be a bit miffed if I had.  The Wurfl project certainly qualifies as open source but something is missing in the spirit.  I understand the desire of the core team to try and monetize the project since they likely did a large portion of the work but people often contribute to this type of project precisely because they want to avoid the more commercial alternatives.

Comment: Timothy, the direction that WURFL has taken was dictated purely by the will to make the project sustainable, and not to take anything away from anyone. Real contributors are still happily on board getting more than enough bang for past and present contributions. If you want to avoid commercial alternatives, you can maintain your own regexps.
BTW, I almost forgot to mention that we launched a Cloud service that also comes with a free offer for the hobbyists and micro-companies: http://www.scientiamobile.com/cloud

Answer (score 5):

There is a free version of [DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com) available for web developers who need an easy and reliable way to distinguish between mobile, tablet, desktop, TV etc. Also identifies OS and browser.  It's available to your web application as a web service built on the DeviceAtlas Cloud infrastructure -

Completely free to use and available in Java .NET PHP Python Ruby

https://deviceatlas.com/blog/announcing-deviceatlas-cloud-free-version

Answer (score 3):

Developers, hobbyists and micro-companies may find the free WURFL OnSite or Cloud offering sufficient for their needs.

WURFL Cloud: http://scientiamobile.com/wurflCloud/gettingStarted

WURFL OnSite: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/dotnet_index.php

In free edition they allow any 2 free properties/capabilities which you can select like-

- ux_full_desktop
- is_wireless_device
- is_tablet
- brand_name
- model_name
- device_os
- device_os_version
- and many more...

This would help in getting just and much more required requesting device info. Hope this helps somebody in need.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apache DeviceMap for .NET: http://devicemap.apache.org

The best (and probably only) Open Source alternative that exists in that area.

Answer (score 0):

After Apache showed too little interest in Mobile projects (there are only 2 active projects in this category, essentially all dominated by client-side Phonegap) especially on the server side, we put DeviceMap to rest in January 2017.

You can find the only true Open Source alternative in this field, free to use both for non-profit and commercial sites at [OpenDDR](http://openddr.mobi).